# Can we call method that exist on aspx page through web service

Tags: asp.net

Can we call a Method that exist on a aspx page through Web Services.

It is like Reflection that method exists in dll form , but is it possible to call method from Aspx page if yes then please tell me how is it?:confused:

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to call a method on an ASPX page?

Comment: I have Report.aspx page that contain grids and one button . By cliking on that button one excel document generated. I have to do this utility by service either windows or web.

Answer (score 2):

The code-behind class in an ASPX page is just a class, so *technically* there is nothing stopping you from doing that. However, it strikes me as a *really* bad idea from code design point of view.

The code in an ASPX page class should be related only to that page. If you need the same functionality elsewhere, move the code for that functionality to some other place (such as a class library that can be called from both places).

Answer (score 0):

You should extract common functionality to a class of its own - this way you can call the code from both the web page and the web service and keep them decoupled from each other.